# Count occurance of NULL in list in R

Tags: r

i want to count occurances of NULL in my list named ->

```
wallet_to_tx_text_json$txs$outputs
```

For this i tried `length(is.NULL(wallet_to_tx_text_json$txs$outputs))` 
but it returns 1 even when there are 7 NULL

MWE

```
install.packages('httr')
require(httr)
install.packages('jsonlite')
require(jsonlite)

caller <- "myemail@add"
i<-"091bc8fe2f7aa8fd"
baseurl1<-"http://www.walletexplorer.com/api/1/wallet?wallet="
end1<-"&from=0&count=100&caller="

call1 <- paste(baseurl1,i,end1,caller,sep="")
wallet_to_tx_address <- GET(call1)
wallet_to_tx_text <- content(wallet_to_tx_address, "text")
wallet_to_tx_text_json <- fromJSON(wallet_to_tx_text, flatten = TRUE)
wallet_to_tx_text_json[["total_coinbase"]] <- length(is.NULL(wallet_to_tx_text_json$txs$outputs))
```

how to do it in R

Comment: Did you try `sum` instead of `length`? And I think the it is `is.na` in R

Comment: no it is giving zero as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wallet_to_tx_text_json$txs$outputs` is a list, you cannot directly use `is.null` on a list. Iterate over the list (using `sapply` or any other method), compare with `is.null` and count the occurrence using `sum`.

```
sum(sapply(wallet_to_tx_text_json$txs$outputs, is.null))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
sum(unlist(lapply(wallet_to_tx_text_json$txs$outputs, is.null)))
```